# Eddy current brake with superconductor

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

There are eddy current brakes used with metal plates to stop trains. It converts kinetic energy of the metal plate to heat via eddy current on it. So what if we have a superconducting metal plate and have made a eddy current brake with it? Will it work? If so, where's the energy gone? If not, what then will happen?

Comment: There are no eddy current in a superconductor as far as I know. Did you heard about such thing somewhere you can justify of ?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't see why it would work because the eddy current loops counteract the flux from the magnet (e.g., it'd be frictionless & no energy loss).

Answer (score 0):

The energy is stored in the current in the superconductor, which has energy equal to $\frac{1}{2}LI^2$, where $L$ is the inductance and $I$ is the current.

Would it work? yes, you would brake the train and store the energy in the superconductor for later reuse.

Is it practical? Probably not; energy is cheap and superconductors are expensive, and there are alternatives that are cheaper.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_magnetic_energy_storage

Comment: How high is this inductance compared to ordinary materials resistance? By the way, as far as I know, there is a current limit for the superconductor to retain its superconductivity.